# Command line server for IE driver has stopped working dialog window while executing test cases on IE11 wth selenium 2.53

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am running a test suite with more than 500 test cases with selenium 2.53 on IE11 browser.
I am getting error "Command line server for the IE driver has stopped working" during the execution randomly and the execution gets stuck.

I've updated IEDriver from 2.48.0 to v3.1.0.0 & v3.2.0.0 but no luck.
I've also tried to add new key "TabProcGrowth" (value = "0") under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" but it didn't help.

OS: Windows 7- 64 bit
Selenium Version: 2.53.0.0
Browser: IE
Browser Version: IE 11.0.9600.18537

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i had faced the same issue but with higher version IE Driver 3.6.0
solution:try with different version

IE Driver 3.3.0 has resolved the issue and even use the same version of            Selenium.Support -Version 3.3.0
Selenium.WebDriver-Version 3.3.0
Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver 3.3.0

please refer this link for detailed description of each version https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG